# Static event for INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: wpf, events, binding

I have this `ObservableCollection` collection with my model and all this collection items are inside `ListView` and i can see it's properties changing with my events that i created inside my class:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

virtual public void NotifyPropertyChange(string propertyName)
{
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

public string FileName
{
    get { return _fileName; }
    set
    {
        _fileName = value;
        NotifyPropertyChange("FileName");
    }
}
```

Now my model has another property that is `static`:

```
public static int counter;
```

So my question is how can i add another event for my static member.

Comment: Can you please explain why you need to Notify your static member mentioned ?

Comment: I want to update my Progress-Bar and if i can do it without timer i prefer this

Comment: what static member does with progress bar ?

Comment: See the EDIT part in the accepted answer to the duplicate question.